# error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState') while using redux store in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Just came across this issue `error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')`  with next.js and redux.

[image]

Here is my code below, I don't know the reason why I am facing this issue.

`pages/app/store.js`

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import counterSlice from "../slices/counterSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        counter : counterSlice
    }
});
```

`pages/slices/counterSlicer.js`

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    count : 0
};

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name : "counter",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        increment : (state , action) => {
            state.count += 1;
        }
    }
});

export const { increment } = counterSlice.actions;

export const getCount = (state) => state.counter.count;

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

**I never had dispatched any action yet, maybe dispatch later**

`pages/_app.js`

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default MyApp;
```

and finally in `pages/index.js`

```
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getCount } from './slices/counterSlice'

export default function Home() {
  const value = useSelector(getCount);
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      The value is {value}
     </div>
  )
}
```

**Note: For more info let me tell you that I have tried the exact code in `react app` also, but the same code is working in react but not working in next.js**

You can check the output of `react` in this image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap props.

Please see this https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/blob/master/packages/demo-redux-toolkit/pages/_app.tsx

Export wrapper from your `store.js`

```
import { createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
...
export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);
```

And your _app.js should be

```js
import '../styles/globals.css'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { wrapper } from './store';

function MyApp({ Component, ...rest }) {
  const { store, props } = wrapper.useWrappedStore(rest);
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Component {...props} />
        </Provider>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```